# Jboss autostart in Linux

Tags: linux, jboss

I've got a Jboss as a service at my Linux machine. I start that with `sudo sh /etc/init.d/jbossas7 start`. The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash### BEGIN INIT INFO  
#chkconfig: 345 90 10
#description: JBOSS 7
#processname: jbossas7
#Provides:          jbossas7  
#Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog  
#Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog  
#Default-Start:     2 3 4 5  
#Default-Stop:      0 1 6  
#Short-Description: Start/Stop JBoss AS 7  
### END INIT INFO   

    ## Include some script files in order to set and export environmental variables  
    ## as well as add the appropriate executables to $PATH.  
    [ -r /etc/profile.d/java.sh ] && . /etc/profile.d/java.sh  
    [ -r /etc/profile.d/jboss.sh ] && . /etc/profile.d/jboss.sh  

    JBOSS_HOME=/home/users/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2 

    AS7_OPTS="$AS7_OPTS -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true"   ## See AS7-1625  
    AS7_OPTS="$AS7_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0"  
    AS7_OPTS="$AS7_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0"  

    case "$1" in  
        start)  
            echo "Starting JBoss AS 7..."  
            #sudo -u jboss sh ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh $AS7_OPTS           ##  If running as user "jboss"  
            #start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --chuid jboss --exec ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh $AS7_OPTS   ## Ubuntu  
            ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh $AS7_OPTS &  
        ;;  
        stop)  
            echo "Stopping JBoss AS 7..."  
            #sudo -u jboss sh ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-admin.sh --connect command=:shutdown            ##  If running as user "jboss"  
            #start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --chuid jboss --exec ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-admin.sh -- --connect command=:shutdown     ## Ubuntu  
            ${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown  
        ;;          

        *)  
            echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/jbossas7 {start|stop}"; exit 1;  
        ;;  
    esac  

    exit 0
```

Also I've executed next commands:

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add jbossas7
sudo /sbin/chkconfig  jbossas7
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --level 123456  jbossas7 on
```

But after rebooting machine JBoss doesn't work. I want to make my server start automatically. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cant comment yet ...
but have you checked your fist line:

```
#!/bin/bash### BEGIN INIT INFO
```

I guess you should try:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# chkconfig: 345 90 10
# description: JBOSS 7
# processname: jbossas7 
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          jbossas7  
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog  
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog  
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5  
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6  
# Short-Description: Start/Stop JBoss AS 7  
### END INIT INFO
```